# how i can reset the page num to 1 when i change to another exposed filter option?

Tags: paging, views

Now,i have a view page with exposed filter(filter option:filterA,filterB) and full pager

when i go to the 3rd page of  **filterA** , change the filter option to **filterB** ,i find the page redirect to the 3rd page of **filterB** ,what can i do to let it redirect to 1st page of **filterB**

Answer (score 2):

Create new filter group in the "Filter Criteria" section of view and add move both the exposed filters in the new group and than apply the "OR" operator between them as below:
[image]

Comment: Maybe i have a wrong description, what i mean is i have only one filter criteria contain some filter options,not 3 filter criteria,and now the issue is that it will direct to optionB's 3rd page when i click optionB on optionA's 3rd page